# jquery ajax post xml param doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, post

I have the below ajax jquery post with xml as param,

```
var params ="requestXML="+requestXML;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GetOfferPts",
        data: params,
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        async:false,
        cache: false,
```

It is throwing `404 not found` or `302 temperorily moved` error in firebug. In my java class i am trying to fetch,

`String requestXML = requestProperties.getString("requestXML", "");`

Comment: is the URL really that?

Comment: It is not the params, it is the URL

Comment: @Spokey ya its my command ...